# Cannot boot USB live to install XUBUNTU 17.04 on an empty hard disk

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I wanted to install Xubuntu 17.04 (I had Windows 10). Via GParted I converted my hard disk from MBR to GPT. 
And that action has deleted  the boot loader. 
I cannot boot to my USB live to install Xubuntu 17.04. My secure boot is disabled. 
Boot-Repair report here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25499895/

Could somebody please help me.

Comment: But you can boot from the Boot-Repair USB boot drive :-) It means that the computer *can* boot from a USB boot drive. Maybe something is wrong with your Xubuntu 17.04 boot drive. Did you check the iso file with md5sum? How did you create the USB drive with Xubuntu 17.04? Please describe what happens (or does not happen)!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I checked succesfully my ISO (SHA256). I before tried with Unetbootin and Lili USB Creator.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Boot-Repair says Secure boot may be on? But it should boot installer in UEFI secure boot or  not. But if Secure Boot is on, it may not boot in BIOS mode. With secure boot you usually have another setting to allow USB boot as that is also not considered Secure.

Comment: Toshiba  Nvidia GEFORCE. Hard disk Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54755. Preinstalled system: Windows 7. How to check the secure boot ?

Comment: When booted from the Boot-Repair USB boot drive, you can run the following command lines and edit the result into your original question. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code': `sudo lsblk -f`;`sudo lsblk -m`;`sudo parted -ls`;`test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` -- Please tell us also the model number of the computer and the model number of the nvidia graphics chip/card, and tell us the exact name of the Xubuntu iso file.

Comment: You check/set/unset the secure boot in the UEFI/BIOS menu system. This is different between computers, so I cannot tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: is your live USB configured to boot UEFI? you need the 64-bit version of ubuntu. the 32-bit version does not yet support EFI boot.

Comment: I finally succeeded in booting. A lot of thanks for your help and your time. I changed an option during making of the USB Live (with Rufus tool): I selected "MBR for UEFI or BIOS" intead of  "GPT for UEFI". And it works! In fact, before booting, I have changed my hard disk from MBR to GPT. That's why I had selected that option.